# associate component to item menu

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How Can I associate a component with a item the menu?

I have two compoment in my Site, when I select the item menu in the administrator I have Menu Item Type to select the type of this item I see Single Article ... and other thing but not my component, any idea!

I create my component with [this](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/) and install withtout problem.

thanks

Comment: You will probably be best off contacting the developer of the component generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A menu item is simply associated with each view you want to have menu items for. In order for Joomla to allow you to create a menu item for a particular view, you have to instruct it with an XML file that defines the parameters are stored for that menu item (if any). You will need to add an XML file here:

```
/JOOMLA/components/YOUR COMPONENT/views/VIEW YOU WANT MENU FOR/tmpl/default.xml
```

This is tutorial is for 1.5, but it will be similar for 2.5. The main difference is that JParameter has been replace by JForm.

http://docs.joomla.org/Component_parameters#2._Menu_item_specific_parameters_3

Comment: Thanks @BrentFriar the problem is fixup